# a digraph representation by structs

Tags: c++, c, graph, graph-theory

I would like to create a digraph. Each Edge has information about `destination Node` and `origin Node` . In addition, each Node has information about list of `incomingEdges` and `outgoingEdges` .

I have an adjacencyMatrix [][] of graph and I want to read the matrix and and create a new graph.

here is code;

```
  struct Node
    {
       vector<Edge *> incomingEdges;
       vector<Edge *> outgoingEdges;
    };

    struct Edge
    {

       struct Node destination;
       struct Node origin;

    };
```

.
.
.
.

```
for(int i=0; i<totalNodes; i++)
{
    struct Node nodei;
}
```

.
.
.
.
.

```
for(int i=0; i<totalNodes; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<totalNodes; j++)
    {
        if ( adjacencyMatrix[i][j] == 1)
        {
            struct Edge edgeij;
            edgeij.destination=nodej;
            edgeij.origin =nodei;
            nodei->outgoing.push_back(edgeij); // ???
            nodej->incoming.push_back(edgeij); // ???

        }
    }
}
```

I m not familiar to C/C++. obviously I need some help to improve it.
How can I push_back to a vector of pointer declared in a struct ?

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: sorry, question is updated. How can I push_back to a vector of pointer declared in a struct ?

Answer (score 1):

When you do :

```
    if ( adjacencyMatrix[i][j] == 1)
    {
        struct Edge edgeij;
        edgeij.destination=nodej;
        edgeij.origin =nodei;
        nodei->outgoing.push_back(edgeij); // ???
        nodej->incoming.push_back(edgeij); // ???
    }
```

The `edgeij` object is destroyed at the end of the block, making it pretty useless (and the code does not compile anyway, since you try to push an object where a **pointer** is expected)

Since your vector is expecting a pointer, you should use a dynamically allocated `Edge` :

```
    Edge* edgeij = new Edge;
    edgeij.destination=nodej;
    edgeij.origin =nodei;
    nodei->outgoing.push_back(edgeij);
    nodej->incoming.push_back(edgeij);
    // now, do not forget to properly delete resources allocated with new
```

A better design solution would be to avoid raw pointer altogether, and prefer smart pointers, e.g. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>>`.

Comment: Also, I would recommend to define a constructor on the Edge class that takes two parameters, i.e. the two nodes, origin and destination. Pretty pointless to create Edge without the nodes. Well, the constructor might even call push_back on the two nodes, making the code in the if block pretty simple, i.e. basically  `new Edge(nodei,nodej)`. Just my two cents.